# Visual studio 2010 , Error MSB3073

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I got the following error.

```
error MSB3073: The command "copy app.config “D:\Projects\Sdk.dll.config”
:VCEnd" exited with code 1. C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 113
```

I did not understand what error it is.

On clicking the error message, it is navigated to the `[Microsoft.CppCommon.targets]` file, to the following code.

```
<Target Name="PostBuildEvent" Condition="'$(PostBuildEventUseInBuild)'!='false'">
    <Message Text="Description: %(PostBuildEvent.Message)" Condition="'%(PostBuildEvent.Message)' != '' and '%(PostBuildEvent.Command)' != ''"/>
    <Exec Command="%(PostBuildEvent.Command)$(BuildSuffix)" Condition="'%(PostBuildEvent.Command)' != ''"/>
  </Target>
```

What is the error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a post-build command which is trying to execute a copy that is failing.  The most likely cause is a user defined command in the vcproj file which is failing.  Check your projects for any block in a post-build task.  That is the likely source of the error